# How does Eclipse IDE resolve File/Resource location?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io, resources

My question is expressed in terms of these

> two Images.

In the first one, **configuration.configure()** method of hibernate loads the

> file from src folder as indicated by red arrows

[image: Eclipse Image 1]

> While in this second image,

it is shown that **PropertyConfigurator.configure()** method of **Log4j** loads the file from

> root folder of Project as indicated by the red arrows again

[image: Eclipse Image 2]

In both projects, this and only this setup works and no alternate setup works.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Eclipse IDE resolve File/Resource location? really!!?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse isn't doing anything, it's all the JVM.  the results would be the same if you used the command line or another IDE.

The different programs load configuration diferently in your 2 examples.

1. Hibernate loads config files as a resource which looks for a file with that path on your class path which is why it can be in `src`.

[sourcode of Hibernate's Configuration#configure(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.7.ga/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java#Configuration.configure%28java.lang.String%29)

2. Log4j uses the String as a path to open a `FileInputStream`.  Since you give a relative path, it looks for a file relative the root of your project

[sourcecode of log4j PropetyConfigruator#configure(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.java?av=h#PropertyConfigurator)

Answer (score 1):

**load hibernate.cfg.xml**

`configuration.configure(hibernate.cfg.xml)` means your hibernate configuration file “hibernate.cfg.xml” is at the root of your project classpath.Even if you don't pass the configuration file name in the configure() method, it will work, but in that case name should be hibernate.cfg.xml.

If you want to place this configuration file into a different directory then you need do like below

```
new Configuration().configure("/com/config/hibernate.cfg.xml")
```

**load log4j.properties**

Loading log4j.properties also works in the similar way.

If you want to put your log4j.properties in to com-->config **source folder** you can do like below

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("classpath:com/config/log4j.properties");
```